# php process array sent via html form

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to send an array via HTML form:

```
<input type='text' name='myvar[]' />
```

How to process it when the form gets submitted? Also, is there any kind of security issues regarding this kind of submission? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like array in `foreach` loop

```
foreach($_POST['myvar'] as $item)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['myvar']` will be an array. No security issues should be worried.